# Insert all combinations of two tables in intermediate table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

### My situation

I'm making a site where people can reserve meeting rooms. On the reservation form for a meeting room, I've some optional field sets like below:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Catering |
| 2 | Coffee break |
| 3 | Drinks |

Here are some example meeting rooms:

| ID | Name | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dog | Brussel |
| 2 | Cat | Antwerpen |
| 3 | Chicken | Brugge |
| 4 | Cow | Gent |

I'm using Microsoft SQL server 2016.

### Database structure

- The fieldsets from the first code block stands inside my database in the table `reservationFieldsets`.
- The meeting rooms stands in the `meetingRooms` table.
- There is an intermediate table named `meetingRoomsReservationFieldsets`.

### Question

Now I'll fill `meetingRoomsReservationFieldsets` with all rooms and all the fieldsets like below:

| RoomID | FieldsetID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |

### I've tried

I've tried to do it manually but there are a lot of rooms and too much to do that manual.

Comment: maybe you're looking for a cross  join. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: you can do this in older syntax too, by using Select * from tableA, TableB

Comment: @Jeremy Please do not encourage bad habits.

Comment: @Jeremy: oke great and how could I insert them into `meetingRoomsReservationFieldsets`?

Comment: you are looking for Insert into...Select https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it by the comments on the question. I use this code:

```
INSERT INTO meetingRoomsReservationFieldsets
SELECT meetingRooms.id, reservationFieldsets.id
FROM reservationFieldsets
CROSS JOIN meetingRooms
```